# Sending Email from mail.domainx.com using c# works for some but not like gmail or yahoo

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, sendmail

I am using following code to send emails to subscribed user using c# from asp.net web application

When i send email using email@domainx.com then email are delivered to most of the client email address but fails for client like gmail or yahoo. Email are not even received by these clients i checked spam folder, added recipient email address to  while list but it always fails

and when i use gmail credential to send email it works. How i can test email service to see why it is failing from email@domainx.com .

Below is the sample code

```
 public static void SendEmailNewsletter(string to, string subject, string message, bool isHtml)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create a new message
                var mail = new MailMessage();

                // Set the to and from addresses.
                // The from address must be your GMail account

                mail.From = new MailAddress("<noreply@xxxx.com>");
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));

                // Define the message
                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = isHtml;
                mail.Body = message;


                var mailclient = new SmtpClient();
               //mailclient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";//ForGmail
               mailclient.Host = "mail.xxx.com";

              //  mailclient.Port = 587; //ForGmail & Microsoft
               mailclient.Port = 25;

                // This is the critical part, you must enable SSL
               // mailclient.EnableSsl = true;//ForGmail
                mailclient.EnableSsl = false;
                mailclient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

                // Specify your authentication details
               // mailclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxx@gmail.com", "xxxx");//ForGmail
                mailclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("noreply@xxx.com", "xxxxxx");

                mailclient.Send(mail);
                mailclient.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

        }
```

Email are being blocked for some reason which i cant figure out why as i dont get any failure message or email from gmail regarding the failure of email being delivered.

Comment: Hi! It seems that problem with your SMTP server through which you are sending messages. Try to contact technical support for your hosting.

Comment: Yes, I think it is more of a configuration problem on the mail server rather than code then why does it work for some email & not gmail, On the other side more confusing is that when i login using webmail.xx.com & send email to same gmail address then it is received by the recipient but not when sent to same email using above c# code. Quite frustrating